# What is the length of a vector after it's components have been squared?

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces

So if $c$ is the length of $(a,b)$ , and $f$ is the length of $(a^2,b^2)$

How do $c$ and $f$ relate?

Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

In some way, they're very easy to compare. $||c||^2 = a^2 + b^2$ and $||f||^2 = a^4 + b^4$. So the ratio of $||c||$ to $||f||$ is $\left( \dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{a^4 + b^4} \right)^{.5}$

But this can be anything, really. If $a,b > 1$, then $||f|| > ||c||$. If $a,b < 1$, then $||f|| < ||c||$. If $a = b = 1$, then $||c|| = ||f||$ In other cases, like when $a > 1$ and $b < 1$, it becomes harder to say. But you can say things like if $a > \sqrt 2$ and $b < 1$, then $||f||$ is at least as big as $||c||$ anyway.

Comment: so it's impossible to express f in terms of just c?

Comment: @DanWebster:  that is correct